# iOS Google SDK fail when change google, gmail password

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

I developed an iOS application and integrate google sign in in Swift language. Below is issue i met, it would be great if you can provide me some advice.

1. Open application, guide user to google sign in ui. Imagine that user sign in success and back to application.
2. Kill the app.
3. Open the app again.

At step3, I will call `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()` and Google SDK sign in success without any issue.

Problem is, at step2, after killing the app. User goes to website and change their goole password.

Now open app again, and Google SDK still sign in success without opening sign in ui again.

I need Google SDK sign in failed because user has already change their password or open sign ui again.

Answer (score 0):

try like this , i hope it will work for you

```
if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {
    // handle signIn succcess case
} else {
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
}
```

// swift

```
if GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().trySilentAuthentication() == true {
    // handle signIn succcess case
} else {
    GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
}
```

Comment: for swift als u can use like that

Comment: Google+ Sign-In is deprecated, and is likely to not function as expected. 
Do not use Google+ Sign-In in new apps. To sign in users with their Google Accounts, use Google Sign-In. See the migration guide to migrate from Google+ Sign-In.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in